# How to clear history in git repo by condition

Tags: git

I have a git repo with 22k commits.
Most of that commits (21k+) - are auto-generated by this repo and app logic.

So, for example, when I do `git log -10 --oneline` I see:

```
825f1f69f some commit3
adc9c98ab [skip ci] Generate yaml files
780644c8d [skip ci] Generate yaml files
35c1d4712 [skip ci] Generate yaml files
6j43d4712 some commit2
2k3j3222j [skip ci] Generate yaml files
125f1f69f [skip ci] Generate yaml files
634264c3f [skip ci] Generate yaml files
634264c3f some commit1
sdkhfs722 [skip ci] Generate yaml files
```

where `some commit${n}` commited by some developers, and `Generate yaml files` are generated by app.

Is it possible somehow to clear git history by some condition, to keep in history commits created by developers, and to clear or squash all `[skip ci] Generate yaml files`, to see final result like:

```
825f1f69f some commit3
6j43d4712 some commit2
634264c3f some commit1
sdkhfs722 [skip ci] Generate yaml files
```

or

```
825f1f69f some commit3
6j43d4712 some commit2
634264c3f some commit1
```

but keep all changes in the project as they are. Need just to delete the history.
Is it possible?

Comment: History is commits, so you'll need to delete commits, as [vmicrobio answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74950912/1256452). Note that no commit can ever be *changed*, which means that to delete some commits, all *subsequent* commits must be copied to new-and-improved commits that have different lineage (different parent hash IDs). The result is a new repository that should *completely replace* the previous repositories; your best bet is to delete the previous repositories (after saving some backup(s) of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try the tool BFG Repo-Cleaner: https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner

EDIT:

You can use BFG Repo-Cleaner tool to remove the auto-generated commits from your git history. The steps are as follows:

1. Install BFG Repo-Cleaner
2. Run BFG Repo-Cleaner with the command:

   bfg --delete-files '*.yaml' --no-blob-protection myrepo.git
3. Push the cleaned repository to the remote:

   git push --force --all

This will remove all commits related to the auto-generated yaml files and keep the commits created by developers in the history.